# Is Brian Finch under the influence of NZT at night when he visits the club to hook up?

Tags: limitless-tv

In episode four of the TV series *Limitless*, Brian Finch appears to be under the influence of NZT late at night.

He sees diagrams of advanced scientific concepts and says he used the drug to turn seduction into an "algorithm" but according to previous information in the series he's only supposed to have access to the drug in the morning which means it should wear off by the evening.

Comment: I suggest editing in why you think he's under NZT. I've only seen the movie, not the series, so maybe it's one of these "duh it's obvious if you've seen it", but still, I think that would improve your question - and refrain people to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking", like what is currently happening.

Comment: Can you tell the episode number?  I am somewhat remembering this episode but would like to rewatch before answer the question

Comment: @Styxsksu ? don't understand, the question says in episode four (4)?

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks for the feedback. I was wondering if anyone understood why it appears that he is under the influence when the plot suggests the influence should wear off during the evening. Just confusing.

Comment: Isn't he used to have some backup pills? maybe he used one of them. I can't remember exactly what happened, but if I get the time, I'll re-watch it